# login with different user level PHP

Tags: php, sql

Please help. What's the problem with this code. I'm trying to create a login with different user level, but when i try to login as admin or other user, it did not direct to the request page.

here's the code

```
<?php
...//the problem goes here, it didn't direct to the request page

if(empty($error)){//if the array is empty , it means no error found
    $query_check = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (email = '$email' AND password= '$password') AND activation IS NULL";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_conn, $query_check);
    if(!$query_check){
    echo "Query Failed";        
    }
    if(@mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){//if match
        $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC); //Assign the result of this query to SESSION Global Variable
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            if($row['role_type']=='admin'){
                header("Location:../views/admin/dashboard.php");
                exit;
            }
            if($row['role_type']=='staff'){
                header("Location:../views/staff/dashboard.php");
            }
            if($row['role_type']=='patient'){
                header("Location: ../views/dafault/home.php");
            }
    }else{
        $msg_error = "Either Your Account is inactive or Email address /Password is Incorrect";
    }
}else{
    echo '<div class="errormsgbox"> <ol>';
    foreach($error as $key => $values){
        echo '  <li>'.$values.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ol></div>';
}

if(isset($msg_error)){
    echo '<div class="warning">'.$msg_error.' </div>';
    }
mysqli_close($db_conn);
}
```

?>

Comment: you should be able to narrow down the issue, and not have to show us all your code

Comment: sorry. I'm trying to direct the page to the user page request, the if statement for selecting different user level doesn't work.

Comment: `echo $row['role_type'];exit();` is it what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

The header function should contain a fully qualified url not a relative file system path.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/views/admin/dashboard.php');
```

Comment: i also tried to replace the if with else if, but still not working.

Comment: well start placing die('messages') in your script until you figure out where it is getting to/not getting to.